# Oracle BI Publisher: Making text item vertical

Tags: oracle, obiee, publisher

I am using Oracle BI Publisher, and I have a report to create that should have text items displayed vertically.

I couldn't find any options to rotate, or make it vertical. If there is any possible way, could someone tell it? Maybe I should use some custom CSS style

P.S. In this particular case, I have a table in a report, and report table headers should be displayed vertical

Edit. I uploaded a image of options that I have
[image]

[image]

Comment: The first search result on google, points me to this - https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/getting-vertical

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that post, but I don't have that option in my BI Publisher.